# Footer place in top of the table

Tags: html, css

I have a footer like this in Layout:

```
  <footer>
        <div class="PiePagina"><img src="~/Content/ImagenCorp/Fondos/banner_inferior.png" alt="" ></div>
    </footer>
```

footer css:

```
.PiePagina  
{
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

and table like this into index:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="empleados">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="importar empleados">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn btn-xs" id="openUpload" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Importar
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin:15px 0 0 0;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive" id="tbl-empleados" style="width: 100%">
      <thead style="">
        <tr>
          <th>Empleado</th>
          <th>Gerente</th>
          <th>Evaluación</th>
          <th>Sueldo Actual</th>
          <th>CR</th>
          <th>Mover a
            <br />Mínimo</th>
          <th>Matriz de
            <br />Mérito</th>
          <th>Ajuste</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Empleados) {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
          <td>@item.vGerente</td>
          <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
          <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
          <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
          <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
        </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

That table can have alot of items. So footer place above of the table (in Internet Explorer) in chrome it seems good. Why it occurs? What am I doing wrong? Regards
[image]

Comment: What css do you have applied? and does the Footer appear before the table in the html?

Comment: @happymacarts Sorry I forget add footer css. I added it to my question. And yes Footer appears before table because before footer in layout I use                            
 `RenderBody()`

Comment: i think it has do to with the order. since the table is rendered after the footer.  and since there is no calc of the table height the footer doesn't know where to go except where the bottom was before the table was rendered. To fix it you may try wrapping the table in a relative positioned div

Answer (score 0):

Have you used float in some element? Maybe cleaning the footer.

```
.PiePagina  
{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I try it but same result

Comment: `position:absolute` must work ( Like [happymacarts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/897320/happymacarts) said )

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what you are trying to say but this code works perfectly fine for chrome and IE. If you want your footer to be on top. Please try this one. I have used inline styling, you can make a class if you want. Please let me know if you have any confusion:

```
 <footer>
   <div class="PiePagina" style="background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"></div>
</footer>
```

PS use your required image whatever you are using in the url I used

Comment: image just disappear.. If I debug it and go to image route. There is, but index don't show it

Comment: Can you show me latest code? I don't know why isn't it working :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

by wrapping everything in a container the footer can be positioned at the bottom of the table by using an `position:absolute;`as i think you intend

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
}

.PiePagina {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <footer>
    <div class="PiePagina"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x80" alt=""></div>
  </footer>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="empleados">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="importar empleados">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn btn-xs" id="openUpload" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Importar
        </button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin:15px 0 0 0;">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-responsive" id="tbl-empleados" style="width: 100%">
        <thead style="">
          <tr>
            <th>Empleado</th>
            <th>Gerente</th>
            <th>Evaluación</th>
            <th>Sueldo Actual</th>
            <th>CR</th>
            <th>Mover a
              <br />Mínimo</th>
            <th>Matriz de
              <br />Mérito</th>
            <th>Ajuste</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="">

          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>@item.vEmpleado</td>
            <td>@item.vGerente</td>
            <td>@item.vEvaluacion</td>
            <td>@item.dSueldoActual.ToString("C2")</td>
            <td>@item.dCR.ToString("P2")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMinimo ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bMerito ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
            <td>@(item.bAjuste ? "Sí" : "No")</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I try it but isn't work... I change button for negative value like: -100px and it works... but I know this is not good practice at all

Comment: what are you adding the "-100px" to?